# Timeout Socket Error #10060 connection timed out Apache web server

Tags: apache, server, timeout

I am attempting to implement data collection software using TradeSoft Inc. ShopPak Mobile. This product uses an Apache Web Server. I have the Web Server running and directing to a subdomain and all is working. However, when I attempt to verify the product license with the product supplier I receive a:

> Connection timed out Socket error: 10060

In the Apache error log I receive this error:

> [Wed Dec 20 00:41:57.784803 2023] [core:error] [pid 14920:tid 1280] ["{client IP}"] AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET ../../proc/ HTTP

I have been told everything is OK on their end and that our SonicWall Firewall is not impacting this.